# Install WindowsAzure.Storage to PCL targeting Xamarin platforms

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, portable-class-library

I need Azure Storage support in my app. I tried to add the nuget package, but I get the error that the dependency Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager doesn't supports my current project. I targeted WP8 and Xamarin.Android.

How can I get it into my PCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WindowsAzure.Storage package doesn't support PCLs.  It looks like there is a preview version that may support Windows Store apps and Windows Phone 8.

You can request that the team add PCL support, or adapt [the source code](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-storage-net/) yourself.

Comment: Why is there platform specific stuff? There are no views are other UI elements :(

Comment: The preview installs over nuget, but windowsazure.storage isn't in my references at all, just some dependencies.

Comment: There is a [user voice topic](http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/5355512-create-a-portable-class-library-pcl-implementati) open for this, if want to request that this be added. I'm definitely missing this as well.

Comment: @Michael did you figure out why windowsazure.storage wasn't appearing in your references?  I am having the same problem.