# Windows Azure Storage and Windows Phone 8.1 Store

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to connect Microsoft Azure's Storage and Windows Phone 8.1 Store app (running on ARM), but I can't.

Firstly, I need to add `WindowsAzure.Storage` lib from nuget. Just after it install, I cannot deploy to ARM device (x86 on Emulator deploying).

Secondly, I create code like this:

```
StorageCredentials sc = new StorageCredentials("ACCOUNT_NAME", "ACCOUNT_KEY==");
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(sc, true);

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("CONTAINER");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.Name.ToLower()); //file is Windows.Storage.StorageFile instance returned by FilePicker.

await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(file);
```

Code working on x86 in Emulator.

After two days of googling I just created folders like `de`, `es` etc in `MSIL` folder of `\obj\ARM`. Now, I can deploy to my ARM-based device. But now my code is not working. I have an error with `CloudBlobClient`:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.ni.DLL
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The argument 'ParallelOperationThreadCount' is larger than maximum of '64'
Parameter name: ParallelOperationThreadCount
```

I don't know how to figure out this ****... But I need to send some data to Azure's Storage Account.

If someone can create an Empty project with connected Azure's Storage and Windows Phone 8.1 Store (ARM), please, send me this solution. Or if you know how to upload blobs and table entities to Azure from REST - give me this solution.

I have contacted with Microsoft via Nuget, but they still didn't respond me.

Comment: Those libraries don't support PCL.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103640/install-windowsazure-storage-to-pcl-targeting-xamarin-platforms